# Why doesn't the .pop function remove letters "u" and "U" from the list vowels when the input contains "Qu"?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

If the word begins with the letters "qu", the letter "u"/"U" should be removed from the list vowels, however, my code doesn't work. How can I fix this?

For context, this code is for converting English to Pig Latin.

```
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]
qu = ["qu", "Qu"]
def firstVowelIndex(w):
    for index, char in enumerate(w):
        if char in vowels:
            return index


def encryptVow(w):
    w = w + "-way"
    return w

def encryptCon(w):
    wordToList = list(w)
    if wordToList[0:2] in qu:
        vowels.pop(4)
        vowels.pop(9)
        index = firstVowelIndex(w)
        return w[index:] + "-" + w[:index] + 'ay'

    vowels.append("y")
    vowels.append("Y")
    index = firstVowelIndex(w)
    return w[index:] + "-" + w[:index] + 'ay'

def encrypt(w):
    wordToList = list(w)
    if wordToList[0] in vowels:
        return encryptVow(w)

    elif wordToList[0] not in vowels:
            return encryptCon(w)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(encrypt("quiz"))
```

Comment: Where is the variable `vowels` defined? Also, the `pop()` method requires an integer, not a string.

Comment: @SciProg I've updated the code with the vowels list and replaced the words with integers. Still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are using `vowels` as a global variable.  It is OK since you call
`encrypt()` only once.  But if you use it multiple times, once the letters 'u' and 'U' are removed, they will not be present after a word starting with 'q' has been encountered.

Each time the function `encrypt()` is called, it appends 'y' and 'Y' multiple times.

Method `pop()` cannot be called with a string, it must be called with an integer.  Use `search()`.

However, add `print(vowels)` at the start of the `firstVowelIndex()` function.  You will see how the `vowels` list changes.

Consult python documentation about global variables.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this should do what you asked in your question.

```py
if word.lower().startswith("qu"):
    vowels.remove("U")
    vowels.remove("u")
```

P.S: You do not have to turn a string into a list because a string is an iterable of characters. As such you can subindex it without needing to change datatype. As such you could have also used something like:

```py
if word[0:2].lower() == "qu":
    vowels.remove("U")
    vowels.remove("u")
```

But I'd say using the string method `startswith()` is more explicit.

Also consider that if you use the same `vowels` list for multiple words. The code above will raise a `ValueError` cause effectively you already removed those vowels before.